# Unable to update 3.13.0-36-generic Kernel in Ubuntu 14.04.5

Tags: 14.04, kernel, updates

I have a Ubuntu 14.04.5 droplet on digitalocean running 3.13.0-36-generic kernel. I read on [digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-protect-your-server-against-the-dirty-cow-linux-vulnerability) that my kernel version is vulnerable so I tried to update my kernel by running

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

But it always said that there is no update available. It says that I'm already running the latest version. But when I run `uname -rv`

It always returns

```
3.13.0-36-generic #63-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 3 21:30:07 UTC 2014
```

I have tried other terminal commands such as

```
apt-get install linux-generic
```

and rebooting the server but it still has 3.13.0-36-generic.

Have I missed something?

UPDATE : As requested by @mikewhatever here is the result of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140416.2)]/ trusty main restricted

#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140416.2)]/ trusty main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Ubuntu's
## 'extras' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
# deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

Comment: 3.13.0-36-generic is very much out of date, the current kernel is 3.13.0-101-generic. Make sure the `linux-image-generic` package is installed, then try updating again. Also, if it is an ARM based server you might be out of luck, as most vendors never release kernel updates.

Comment: @mikewhatever I tried to install it but it returned : linux-image-generic is already the newest version.
linux-image-generic set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: Strange, ...so what kind of device is it? What's the output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo`?

Comment: @mikewhatever here it is 

processor : 0
vendor_id : GenuineIntel
cpu family : 6
model  : 62
model name : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630L v2 @ 2.40GHz
stepping : 4
microcode : 0x1
cpu MHz  : 2399.998
cache size : 15360 KB
physical id : 0
siblings : 1
core id  : 0
cpu cores : 1
apicid  : 0
initial apicid : 0
fpu  : yes
fpu_exception : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp  : yes

Comment: It's not an ARM device, so let's look at the sources: `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`. Please add the output to the question itself, not as a comment.

Comment: Hm..., not sure really. How about searching for what kernel versions are available: `apt-cache search linux-image-3.13.0-*`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48531/discussion-between-webchun-and-mikewhatever).

Comment: I see that you are using an unofficial mirror for the Ubuntu archives, maybe it s out of date and does not provide the latest kernel; look at `apt-cache policy linux-generic` to find out, normally the latest version should be `3.13.0.101.109`. It is also possible that the latest kernel is installed but not booted (see, `ls /boot/vmlinuz*`), you'd have to look at your GRUB settings.

Comment: @fkraiem here's what I got for ls /boot/vmlinuz@ : /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-101-generic  /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-42-generic
/boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-74-generic. And for apt-cache policy linux-generic , I got this : linux-generic:
  Installed: 3.13.0.101.109
  Candidate: 3.13.0.101.109
  Version table:
 *** 3.13.0.101.109 0
        500 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.13.0.24.28 0

Comment: This is very weird. You do have the latest version installed, but it is not booted, and moreover the version that is booted is one that is not even installed... If your server is a VPS, maybe the kernel is managed at the host level, in which case you'd need to contact your provider. Also, please add the outputs to your question so they are properly formatted.

Comment: Guys, thanks a lot for your helps. I finally managed to solve the problem by following the Digital Ocean support's instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is DigitalOcean that implemented some changes on how they handle kernels. 
To manage the kernels internally I need to select DigitalOcean Grubloader v02 kernel from the kernel drop down in the DigitalOcean control panel.
I'm able to configure Grub to boot from the kernel I preferred after **power off** the server, because **rebooting** will not make change